# How do I get all public static methods of a class in Java?

Tags: java

`clazz.getDeclaredMethods()` will returns all methods, but I only want those `public static` methods, how do I make it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check with the [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class after calling `getModifiers` on the `Method` objects

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   //Read user input into the array
    Method method = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
    int modifiers = method.getModifiers();
    System.out.println(modifiers);

    System.out.println(Modifier.isStatic(modifiers));
    System.out.println(Modifier.isPublic(modifiers));
    System.out.println(Modifier.isAbstract(modifiers));
}
```

prints

```
9
true
true
false
```

The `int` value holds information in specific bit positions for `static`, `public`, etc. modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

you should iterate over the methods returned and check getModifiers() method.
If it returns STATIC or not.

More info in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#STATIC)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
  Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers()).
```

Example:

```
public static List<Method> getStaticMethods(Class<?> clazz) 
{
    List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();

    for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) 
    {
        if (Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) 
        {
            methods.add(method);
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(methods);

}
```